# Delete the first character of certan line in file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Here I want to delete the first character of file of certain lines. For example:

```
>cat file1.txt
10081551
10081599
10082234
10082259
20081134
20081159
30082232
10087721
```

From 3rd line to 7th line delete the first character `sed` command or any else and output will be:

```
>cat file1.txt
10081551
10081599
0082234
0082259
0081134
0081159
0082232
10087721
```

Comment: @anishsane no need for anchor: `sed '3,7s/.//'` since `g` is not used, `.` will hit on first character only.

Comment: ^^ Yes, you are right. Somehow, I am used to writing `^.`, for clarity &... habit.. :-/

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -i '3,7s/.//' file1.txt

sed -i.bak '3,7s/.//' file1.txt # to keep backup
```

From `3rd` to `7th` line, replace the first character with nothing.

Comment: bash comments start with #, not within /**/ ;-)

Comment: that was not a bash comment by the way... just for the OP to know.. i'll change to avoid confusion :-) thanks

Comment: @A.M.D: Please provide me another solution for the edit which I had done in this question. Thanks & Regards

Comment: Ideally, you should have asked it as a new questions, anyway, this will do it for u : sed '/meta-yocto-bsp/a /home/neeraj/yocto/poky/meta-ti \\' text . Use -i for inplace substitution. If not clear, please ask as new question

Answer (score 1):

This is simple in either sed:

```
sed -i '3,7 s/^.//'
```

or Perl:

```
perl -i -pe 's/^.// if $. >= 3 && $. <= 7'
```

Comment: You do not need to anchor the `.`, since you it will hit on the first character on the line and you do not have `g` global.

Comment: @Jotne: That's an interesting point. You're correct, of course; but I think that `s/^.//` is clearer.

Comment: @ruakh: Please provide me another solution for the edit which I had done in this question. Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` program can do this with:

```
pax$ sed '3,7s/.//' file1.txt
10081551
10081599
0082234
0082259
0081134
0081159
0082232
10087721
```

substituting the first character on the line that matches `.` (which is the first character on the line).

I'll also provide an `awk` solution. It's a little more complex but it's worth learning since it allows for much more complex operations than `sed`.

```
pax$ awk 'NR>=3&&NR<=7{sub("^.","",$0)}{print}' file1.txt
10081551
10081599
0082234
0082259
0081134
0081159
0082232
10087721
```

Answer (score 1):

For your 2nd question:

1. if the ending quote is on the last line of the file:

   ```
   sed '$i\
     /home/neeraj/yocto/poky/meta-ti \\
   ' text
   ```
2. to match the end of the continued lines (this one feels fragile)

   ```
   sed '   
       /BBLAYERS.*"/ {
           :a
           /\\$/ {N; ba}
           s@"$@/home/neeraj/yocto/poky/meta-ti \\\n"@
       }
   ' text
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of the `awk`

```
awk 'NR~/^[3-7]$/{sub(".","")}1' file
10081551
10081599
0082234
0082259
0081134
0081159
0082232
10087721
```